# Cosmos DB unique key

Tags: nosql, azure-cosmosdb, unique-key

It is possible to create unique constraint on property in subcollection in json?
I have json like that:

```
{
"id":111,
"DataStructs":[
   "Name": "aaaaa",
   "DataStructCells": [
      {
          "RowName": "Default",
          "ColumnName": "Perfect / HT",
          "CellValue": "0.1"
       },
       {
          "RowName": "Default",
          "ColumnName": "100% / HT",
          "CellValue": "0.2"
       }
    ]
]
}
```

And I wanted to add unique key to prevent to add two the same `RowName: Default`
When I create collection I added unique key: `/DataStructs/DataStructCells/RowName` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is impossible. Unique keys can only work with different documents within a logic partition. To achieve your requirement, you can split your array to different documents in a same logic partition. You can refer to this [How do I define unique keys involving properties in embedded arrays in Azure Cosmos DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61312837/how-do-i-define-unique-keys-involving-properties-in-embedded-arrays-in-azure-cos)