# How to prevent entering duplicate data in Cosmos DB?

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I have a container with `id` as partition key. Based on some condition, I do not want to enter duplicate data in my container, but I am not sure how to do that in Cosmos. i.e., I tried to create unique keys, but that didn't help me.

**Condition:**

Record will be duplicate if `name + addresses[].city + addresses[].state + addresses[].zipCode` are same.

**Document:**

```
{
    "isActive": false,
    "id": "d94d7350-8a5c-4300-b4e4-d4528627ffbe",
    "name": "test name",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "address1": "718 Old Greenville Rd",
            "address2": "",
            "city": "Montrose",
            "state": "PA",
            "zipCode": "18801",
            "audit": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

**Findings:**

- Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/61317715, unique keys cannot include arrays. Unfortunately, I cannot change the document structure. So unique key approach is not the option.

**Questions:**

- Do I need to change partition key? Not sure if I can have `/id#name` (or something like that) in Cosmos like Dynamo?
- Is there any other way of handling this at DB level?

As a last resort, I can add the logic in my code to do this but that would be expensive in terms of RU/s.

Comment: You'll need to figure out how to include your unique content in a non-array property. Uniqueness in an array doesn't really work anyway, since your array can grow infinitely (well, up until the maximum document size), and you would need to re-check for uniqueness with every addition to your array (across all arrays in every document, every time you added to an array).

Comment: And if you really want addresses to be unique, then you should consider storing each address as its own document (where you can now have a composite key across various properties), and then reference such addresses within your main document (e.g. an array of address document id's).

Comment: @DavidMakogon your second comment makes sense. Let me see what I can do here. Thank you.